# Area 51 doesn't show how to propose a new site in FAQ

Tags: feature-request, area-51, site-faq

It seems to me that Area 51 should tell how to propose a new site. However, this is what it says to do to create a site:

> **How do I start a new site?**
>
> If your area of expertise doesn't already have a Stack Exchange site,
>   propose it! Stack Exchange sites are free to create and free to use.
>   All we ask is that you have an enthusiastic, committed group of expert
>   users who check in regularly, asking and answering questions.
>
> The creation of Stack Exchange sites is a democratic, community-driven
>   process. That does not mean the majority of Area 51 users have to love
>   your site idea. It simply means you have to recruit a community of
>   users large enough so that questions get good answers quickly. Reach
>   out to other experts to build support for your site; bloggers,
>   enthusiasts, and support groups can all benefit from a world-class,
>   canonical collection of expert answers to the hardest questions.

Note that it mentions finding a group of experts (Which is important), but doesn't say anything about the mechanics of proposing something. It seems that this is a bit of a mis-hap. I do know that it says on the bottom of the main site, as listed below, but it still seems like that should be in the FAQ...

> Can't find what you're looking for? Select a category listing to the
>   left and propose your site there!

Comment: Well, searching the meta (discussion zone) for "how to start new proposal" gives [this](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/how-can-i-start-a-proposal) but I agree it's confusing and better be in the faq as well.